# 1DPoisson equation with Dirac delta

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, finite-element-method

I was writing my own FEM method to solve the Poisson equation

\begin{align}
-u'' &= \exp(-c(x-1/2)^2)\\
u(0) &= u(1) = 0
\end{align}

where c=100.

and I'm reading from the book of Mats G. Larson, Fredrik Bengzon, "The Finite Element Method: Theory, Implementation, and Practice".

At page [42](http://matematicas.unex.es/~coco/Modelizacion/FEMLarson_Bengzon.pdf) there's the solution via an adaptive method of the equation. In my implementation, I obtain the same result, but the peak is   higher, as in the following figure.

[[image: 2]]

But, if I run my code with c=1000, I obtain the same solution of the picture of the book. So I suspect that the authors plotted the solution for c=1000 instead of c=100. I tried to solve the equation with Wolfram *Mathematica*, but I can't find it.

Can anyone confirm the solution for $c=100$?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This seems to confirm your suspicions that the plot in the book was obtained with $c=1000$:

```
ParametricNDSolveValue[{-u''[x] == Exp[-c (x - 1/2)^2], u[0] == 0, u[1] == 0}, u[x], {x, 0, 1}, c];
Plot[%[1000], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: plot]

I also confirm that I obtained the plot you got for $c=100$.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, Marco!

Answer (score 8):

MarcoB's answer is certainly the way to go to verify the result from the book. Nevertheless, I'd like to show a different approach that is geared towards verifying your FEM code. The finite element low level functions can help in doing that.

We start by setting up your PDE.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
sregion = Line[{{0}, {1}}];
vars = {x};
vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables", "Space"} -> {{u}, 
     vars}];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData["Space" -> ToNumericalRegion[sregion]];


With[{c = 1000},
 cdata = InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd
    , "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{{{-1}}}}
    , "LoadCoefficients" -> {{Exp[-c (x - 1/2)^2]}}];
 ]
bcdata = InitializeBoundaryConditions[vd, 
   sd, {{DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, True]}}];
```

We use a first order mesh, as I assume that your code uses first order too.

```
mdata = InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {"MeshOrder" -> 1}}];
```

Here comes the benefit. `DiscretizePDE` can be used to both assemble the system matrices and to store the elements computed. We will look at those later.

```
(* save the computed elements and assemble the system matrices *)
ddata = DiscretizePDE[cdata, mdata, sd, "SaveFiniteElements" -> True, 
   "AssembleSystemMatrices" -> True];

dbcs = DiscretizeBoundaryConditions[bcdata, mdata, sd];

l = ddata["LoadVector"];
s = ddata["StiffnessMatrix"];
DeployBoundaryConditions[{l, s}, dbcs];
result = LinearSolve[s, l];
```

Now you can inspect the result from the LinearSolve step and generate an interpolating function.

```
if = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mdata["ElementMesh"]}, result];
Plot[if[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Looking at

```
ddata["LoadElements"]
```

and

```
ddata["StiffnessElements"]
```

Provides you with the computed values per element. You can use these to cross check your code. Or you could use NDSolve`ProcessEquations as an equation preprocessor for your own code:

```
femd = With[{c = 1000}, 
   NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{-u''[x] == Exp[-c (x - 1/2)^2], 
       u[0] == 0, u[1] == 0}, u[x], {x, 0, 1}, 
      Method -> "FiniteElement"][[1]]["FiniteElementData"]
   ];

femd["PDECoefficientData"]["DiffusionCoefficients"]
(* {{{{-1}}}} *)

femd["PDECoefficientData"]["LoadCoefficients"]
(* {{E^(-1000 (-(1/2) + x)^2)}} *)
```

Comment: Many thanks, it confirmed the correctness of  my code! :)